# "No module named 'stem'" in Python3 on macOS

Tags: python, tor, stem

Apologies for the noob question. 
I am trying to run a script which uses the stem module. However, whenever I run it, I get the warning "ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'stem'"

Even when I use Python3 in terminal this issues occurs from simply trying:

```
In [1]: import stem
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ModuleNotFoundError                       Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-1-e9a7ebd02e09> in <module>()
----> 1 import stem

ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'stem'
```

Why is this happening?
I am using macOS 10.12.6. I have also imported stem through terminal.

Comment: As it says, you don’t have the `stem` module installed. You need to run `sudo pip install stem`, or if you don’t have root access, `pip install --user stem`. You can look [here](https://packaging.python.org/tutorials/installing-packages/) for more options regarding package installation.

Answer (score 3):

Try below code

```
pip3 install stem
```

Answer (score 2):

Run It to solve the issue:

```
pip3 install stemming
```

Answer (score 0):

I had similar issue using python3.8,
stem package was installed, had Ubuntu 20.04 system, but still kept on getting the "No module named 'stem'" error.

until I ran into [stem documentation](https://stem.torproject.org/download.html) then figured I should run:

```
sudo apt-get install python3-stem
```